# Swift - Does not play different sound when different sound is selected

Tags: ios, swift, audio

In Swift, when a different sound is selected in a TableView, the name of the sound is added to a variable. In a different view controller, it is supposed to access the variable and play the sound when a button is pressed, though it instead just plays the same sound. Here is the code:

FirstSoundController (Plays Sound):

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var someVariable = SecondViewController()
    @IBAction func activation(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.titleLabel!.text == "ACTIVATE" {
            sender.setTitle("DEACTIVATE", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            var someSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(someVariable.soundSelected, ofType: "mp3")!)

            audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: someSound, error: nil)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
        else {
            sender.setTitle("ACTIVATE", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            audioPlayer.stop()
        }
    }
}
```

SecondViewController (Shows table of Sounds):

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    var sounds = ["BananaSlap", "GlassBreaking", "scream", "WoodyWood", "LaughAndApplause", "EvilLaugh", "Grenade", "BadamTss", "BombExploding"]
    var soundSelected:String?
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sounds.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = sounds[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        var soundSelected = sounds[indexPath.row]
        println(soundSelected)
    }

}
```

Comment: Just saying, I am trying to go through all these solutions and seeing if any of them work. I have tried the delegate solution and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I can immediately spot an error in your `SecondViewController`, being that you've redeclared `soundSelected` as a local variable within the function, ignoring the property. So, instead of:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    var soundSelected = sounds[indexPath.row]
    println(soundSelected)
}
```

I would try:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    soundSelected = sounds[indexPath.row]
    println(soundSelected)
}
```

Comment: Fixed issue, same problem occurs.

Comment: I notice that you're also doing `var someVariable = SecondViewController()` in the action handler. Wouldn't this re-initialise a brand new `SecondViewController` each time?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally typed that line in the wrong part of the code, will edit now.

Comment: The same problem still occurs

Comment: What's triggering the IBAction `"activation:"`?

Comment: A Button inside a UIView in FirstViewController.

Comment: Gotcha—I'm writing a new answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Just change a basic thing. Try this:

1. Declare a property named `soundName` in `AppDelegate`.
2. While selecting the sound to be played initialize `soundName` with the selected sound name.
3. `FirstViewController` get the `soundName` from `AppDelegate` and play the sound.

You can use `AppDelegate` for these types of basic data sharing throughout the app. There is a lot of other ways to do this, like you can store the sound name in `NSUserDefault` and access it from there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `audioPlayer` is only being re-assigned (with `someVariable.soundSelected`) when `activation:` is called. Consequently, when a row is selected in the table view—it simply records this, without initiating any action that may change what `audioPlayer` is currently playing. So the behaviour you describe is actually expected. To achieve what you're after—quite a few solutions come to mind, namely:

- Using [delegation](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/04/08/how-delegation-works-a-swift-developer-guide/) to let `FirstViewController` know when a cell is selected, so that it may then re-assign the `audioPlayer`.
- Using [notifications](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/) (if you'd rather keep them reasonably separate) so that `FirstViewController` observes for a notification that `SecondViewController` posts when a cell is tapped (it need not pass a value, just trigger a reload of the `audioPlayer`
- Moving the `audioPlayer` to a global scope, along with a global function that takes in a sound's name as a parameter and simply reloads the `audioPlayer` with it. That way, both classes don't have to communicate with each other and the audio can be set respectively. This makes more sense to me (or at least having a separate class that deals with the audio, as it is more of a 'singular' entity)

Comment: Just checking, by "reloading the audioPlayer" you do mean audioPlayer.prepareToPlay() right?